# Obtener el índice de un elemento en un array en php (caso especial)

Tags: php, array

Quiero obtener el indice cuando busco alguno de los valores siguientes, ya probé con todas las funciones y no lo he logrado. En el siguiente ejemplo, al buscar 35, 36,37,38,0 39 quiero que me de "Sobrepeso":

```
<?php
$gender2 = "mujer";
$age2 = 25;
$weight2 = 36;
function calculaDatos($gender2, $age2, $weight2){
$datos2 = [
        "mujer" => [
                25 => [
                    "bajo peso" => 25,
                    "Peso standar" => 30,
                    "sobrepeso" => [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
                        ]
                ]
        ];


$buscar = array_search($weight2, $datos2[$gender2][$age2]);
var_dump($buscar);
echo ''.$buscar.'';
}

calculaDatos($gender2, $age2, $weight2)
?>
```

Comment: El array `$datos2` no es consistente. ¿Por qué "mujer" tiene unas llaves (`bajo peso`, `peso estandar`...) y "hombre" tiene otra llamada `edad`, sin las categorías de peso? ¿Qué significan los valores dentro de los arrays más internos?

Comment: Si ya probaste con todas las funciones, compártenos tu intento con [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: @aeportugal Ya quite parte del array para que no distrajera, espero que este mas claro ahora, como ves?

Comment: @Sal esa funcion me puede dar los indices [0], [1], [2], [3] o [4] de los valores 35,36,37,38 y 39 respectivamente, pero NO me va a indicar que estan en "sobrepeso".

Comment: Si agregas tu intento te podemos decir cómo. De cualquier manera determinar *sobrepeso* por tablas es cuestionable, es mejor usar la fórmula del [*IMC*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Índice_de_masa_corporal).

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que debes [normalizar](https://www.google.com/search?q=normalizacion+de+datos) el array y hacer los cálculos dentro de la lógica de la función.

No entiendo bien los datos iniciales, pero se me ocurre que puedes poner los límites, tanto de edad como de peso, y luego se calculará si los valores se encuentran dentro de esos límites dados en los argumentos.

La parte de [array_reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reverse.php) es porque la comparación se hace desde la mayor edad a la menor, y `true` (preserve_keys) es para que la instrucción no reindexe el array.

En los arrays más internos, el primer valor es el límite inicial del "peso estandar" y el segundo es el límite del "sobrepeso".

Puedes agregar o quitar rangos de edad. Debe ser de forma ordenada, de lo contrario usar [arsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.arsort.php).

```php
<?php

function calculaDatos($gender2, $age2, $weight2) {
    $datos2 = [
        "mujer" => [
            0  => [12, 20], // De 0 a 14 años
            15 => [14, 23], // Exclusivamente 15 años
            16 => [18, 25], // De 16 a 34
            35 => [20, 27]  // 35+ años
        ],
        "hombre" => [
            0  => [16, 23], // 0 a 17
            18 => [19, 27]  // 18+
        ]
    ];

    foreach(array_reverse($datos2[$gender2], true) as $age_key=>$winfo) {
        if($age2 >= $age_key) {
            if($weight2 >= $winfo[1]) {
                return 'sobrepeso';
            } elseif($weight2 >= $winfo[0]) {
                return 'peso estandar';
            } else {
                return 'peso bajo';
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```php
// Uso: calculaDatos($genero, $edad, $peso);
echo calculaDatos("mujer", 9, 13); // peso estandar
echo calculaDatos("mujer", 15, 13); // peso bajo
echo calculaDatos("mujer", 45, 32); // sobrepeso
echo calculaDatos("hombre", 25, 22); // peso estandar
```